# How to develop/build Javascript monorepo project like Visual Studio projects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yarnpkg, package.json

In a typical .NET Core project (with Visual Studio 2019) we have a structure like this:

```
Example/
|-- Example.Common/
|   |-- FileExample1.cs
|   |-- FileExample2.cs
|   `-- Example.Common.csproj
|-- Example.WebAPI/
|   |-- Controllers/
|   |-- Program.cs
|   |-- Startup.cs
|   `-- Example.WebAPI.csproj
|-- Example.CLI/
|   |-- Program.cs
|   `-- Example.CLI.csproj
|-- Example.sln
```

In this project, both `Example.CLI` and `Example.Web.API` references the `Example.Common` project. The `Example.sln` file have references to all three `*.csproj` and each csproj have its own dependencies, that can be of one of these 4 kinds:

```xml
<!-- It is a NuGet package (similar to Node.js npm packages) that always resolves from the public nuget.org registry -->
<PackageReference Include="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core" Version="2.18.3" />

<!-- It is local, never resolves from registry -->
<ProjectReference Include="../Example.Common/Example.Common.csproj" />

<!-- Resolves from a machine-wide installed DLL -->
<Reference Include="Global.Dependency.Example" />

<!-- Resolves from a local DLL -->
<Reference Include="Local.Dependency.Example">
  <HintPath>path/to/Local.Dependency.Example.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

When running local during development, if I change something in the Common source code and run the CLI project, it automatically rebuilds the Common and copy the DLL to the destination so the CLI can run a version with these latest changes. Even if I have more projects in the solution, it will just rebuild the projects that the CLI depends and if there are any changes on it since the last run.

When deploying, it rebuilds everything and resolve the local dependencies locally. My problem with Node.js and NPM packages is that:

- When it gets easy for local development, it gets hard to deploy and generate the docker image.
- When it gets easy to deploy and generate the docker image, it gets hard for local development.

I want do the same thing in a Node.js project, share the `common` source code to be used in `web-api` and `cli`, and I want to break each one of these components of the project in a npm package, so each package can have its own dependencies.

In a Node.js project, I have a similar structure:

```
example/
|-- common/
|   |-- file-example1.js
|   |-- file-example2.js
|   `-- package.json
|-- web-api/
|   |-- controllers/
|   |-- index.js
|   |-- routes.js
|   `-- package.json
|-- cli/
|   |-- index.js
|   `-- package.json
|-- package.json
```

The problem is how Node.js and npm/yarn/pnpm resolves the dependencies. I tried using Yarn Workspaces, Lerna, Lerna + Yarn Workspaces, but it seems that all these tools were made for packages that are published to registries, and not to help modularize a single project.

What I want is an easy way to do this:

- When developing local, make changes in the common source code and run the web-api or cli with an updated version of common, without need to call `yarn install` every time or creating `npm link` manually
- When deploying, resolve the dependencies using the local source code / build, and build it in the correct order

I tried:

- Yarn `link:` protocol, works good for development, but when I run `yarn install --production` it tries to resolve using the registry. Won't work because any of my packages will never be publish to any registry.
- NPM `file:` protocol, works good for deployment, but for development, when I make changes in the common package, I need to delete the common folder inside `node_modules` and run `yarn install` again. Even with `file:` protocol, I still need a way to build in the correct order, otherwise, npm/yarn would copy just the source code of the dependencies to the destination node_modules folder.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:**

```
lerna bootstrap
lerna run dev
```

`bootstrap` will install dependencies to the respective packages.
Example:  `common` should be installed in `web-api`.
Lerna will install `common` in `web-api` as a `node_module`.

in `package.json` adding `private: true` will also ensure lerna publish will not publish those projects.

---

**(Long answer:)**

Given the folder directory

```
example/
|-- common/
|   |-- file-example1.js
|   |-- file-example2.js
|   `-- package.json
|-- web-api/
|   |-- controllers/
|   |-- index.js
|   |-- routes.js
|   `-- package.json
|-- package.json
```

---

**1. Yarn workspaces**.

example/package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": ["common", "web-api"]
}
```

Initialise yarn in respective sub-folders.

**Terminal**

```sh
~/example         $ cd ./common
~/example/common  $ yarn init -y
~/example/common  $ cd ../web-api
~/example/web-api $ yarn init -y
```

in example/common/package.json

```
{
  "name": "common",
  "version": 1.0.0
  ...
}
```

in example/web-api/package.json

```
{
  "name" "web-api",
  "dependencies": {
    "common": "1.0.0"
  }
}
```

**Terminal** *(whilst in web-api dir)*

```sh
~/example/web-api $ yarn install
```

In the root directory there should be a `node_modules` which should include:

```
web-api/
common/
```

`yarn` will create a symlink between the `common` and `webapi` from the node_modules folder that is created at the root level.

However, `yarnpkg` convention is to use

```
{
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": ["packages/"]
}
```

Reference: [Ben awad tutorial on yarn workspaces](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G8KXFWftCg0)

---

**2. lerna**

Lerna uses yarn workspaces under the hood [ref](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/pull/899) but you require a `lerna.json` config (which can specify the package manager you require *npm, yarn...*)

lerna.json

```
{
  "packages": [
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "version": "0.0.0"
}
```

There's extra commands in `lerna` such as:
- `lerna diff common` which will give you the git diff since the last commit, or. 
- `lerna run test` which will run the `test` script in each of your packages. (use `--scope={common}` to only target `common test` script).

In [`create-react-app`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/lerna.json) they also include a "changelog" field which i assume would how people would automatically prefix their commit messages.

Reference: [Ben awad tutorial on lerna](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p6qoJ4apCjA)